# Roles using JWT token in Spring boot

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have been trying to add user roles in my Spring boot application, but i'm getting error code: 403 forbidden.

This is my securtiy configuration :-

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .and().addFilterBefore(new FirebaseIdTokenFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/test").hasAuthority("ROLES_ADMIN")
    }
```

And i have this key "authorities" in my JWT token.

```
 {"authorities": "ROLES_ADMIN"}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: your jwt token should not contain this type of object. It is a string of 3 parts

Comment: This is from a decoded JWT token.

Comment: do you allow grand authorities in your UserDetailsIml ??

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: please post your full spring security debug logs as they will tell you for what reason you are getting the 403

Comment: @tuhin47 Thanks, it was because i didn't allow grand authorities.